# Separating common logic into an interface

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns

I order to achieve the `DRY` principle I want a functionality that logs processing time of some other functionality for example for each group of classes with a `Base` class.

So the most logical way is to place it in an `abstract` class and make a `virtual` method between the `StopWatch` `Start` and `Stop`. But I was thinking about if I can separate this functionality into an interface.

My Base class would then implement `IProcessingTimeCalculator`. Is this possible or am I overthinking?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. Could you perhaps add a snippet of pseudo-code to illustrate what the abstract class or interface would do?

Comment: "functionality that logs processing time of some other functionality" that could be a "cross cutting concern" of Aspect Oriented Programming. Or implemented with a "Decorator" for the base class.

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is how to log the processing time of certain method calls, not separating logic into an interface.

Comment: You'll want something like Log4Net. And if you are really interested in performance, logging is not the appropriate tool. There are performance bench-marking tools you can use to measure execution time without the overhead of a general purpose logging tool. Virtual method calls do cost more in terms of processing time, so utilizing those just to measure performance won't give you as accurate a reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces are just declarations and cannot contain implementation. Therefore, an interface cannot contribute any functionality the way a base class can do.

Other languages have traits and mixins that are like an interface or abstract base class, except that they allow a kind of multiple inheritance. C# doesn't have those.

If you need to combine additional functionality, you should likely use *composition, not inheritance*. You can give your classes a `ProcessingTimeCalculator` or `StopWatch` *object*, and then call the methods of that object.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me on `Composition over Inheritance`.

Comment: When C# 8 is released, I need to remember to go back and find every C# answer that says "Interfaces are just declarations and cannot contain implementation" and downvote them for being wrong... ;)

Comment: @David Arno - Do it.  Do it now.